# Finding the limit of the following sequence: $\left(\frac{2m^2 + m + 4}{2m^2 + 3m + 5}\right)^{3m-3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> So I am trying to find 
>   $$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\frac{2m^2 + m + 4}{2m^2 + 3m +5}\right)^{3m-3} $$

I believe this should be represented as $e$ somehow to the power of something, however I can't get to do the algebra in the right way to get to $e$ , I divide by $2m^2$ but then I don't know what to do next.

Comment: you should learn the standard limits from the table, it will definitely help you. You should also search before asking because this question is an abstract duplicate, that is my experience, I'm just a student (:

Comment: An alternative approach would be to say $y = \lim_\limits{m\to \infty} q(m)^{3m-1} \implies \ln y = \lim_\limits{m\to \infty} (3m-1) \ln q(m).$  Use L'Hopital's rule to show that $\ln y = -3$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the correct hint of the user @gt6989b, I add my solution to your limit.

$$\left(\frac{2m^2 + m + 4}{2m^2 + 3m +5}\right)^{3m-3}=\left[\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{2m^2+3m+5}{2m+1}}\right)\right)^{\left(\dfrac{1-\dfrac{2m^2+3m+5}{2m+1}}{1-\dfrac{2m^2+3m+5}{2m+1}}\right)}\right]^{3m-3}$$

$$\left[\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{2m^2+3m+5}{2m+1}}\right)\right)^{\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{2m^2+3m+5}{2m+1}}\right)}\right]^{\dfrac{6m^2+\ldots}{-2m^2+\cdots}}$$

Hence we have $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\frac{2m^2 + m + 4}{2m^2 + 3m +5}\right)^{3m-3}=e^{-3}=1/e^3$$

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? To make computations easier I split what is inside the brackets to: (...)^3m . (...)^-3 Since the second term would go to 1. Then when I take out $e$ what I am left converges to -3, so my final answer is $e^{-3}$

Comment: @Daniel Now it is correct :-)

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

$$
\frac{2m^2 + m + 4}{2m^2 + 3m +5}
 = 1 - \frac{2m + 1}{2m^2 + 3m +5}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Did you manage to simply see that you can factor out 1 since in the numerator there is an extra 2m + 1 and you simply deduced it or is there a more general approach/formula, like if the polynomial is a bit bigger and it is not so obvious that you could factor out 1?

Comment: @Daniel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: @Daniel as long as degree of the top is not smaller, you can do long division. Especially easy here